# Error with postfix gmail smtp on ubuntu

Tags: postfix

I have setup the postfix-gmail-smtp on my GCP instance and it was working for past few months but stopped working now. I have checked and re-installed based on the steps mentioned in https://tonyteaches.tech/postfix-gmail-smtp-on-ubuntu/ but not still not working. Any suggestion on how to fix this issue ?

Br,
Ranjeeta

Comment: Please provide your actual postfix configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about other countries but I know in the UK on May 30th 2022 Google disabled the *l**ess secure apps*** access to gmail.

This means that Google no longer allows other apps to logon to gmail using just your account username and password.

Now you have to enable ***2-step-verification*** on Google and then configure an ***App Password*** on your Google account. Then use that generated App Password for the mail password in your IMAP or SMTP config.

See:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

https://www.gmass.co/blog/gmail-smtp/

Comment: I have setup the 2 step-verification on Google /Gmail but still does not work. I am not getting an error message now. Any idea what file should I refer here for potential error log ?

Comment: @RSingh you say you setup `2-step-verification` but have you do not say you have configured an `App Password`? Please confirm you have done both.

Comment: yes you right it works and it is because my 2 step verification and password was not setup correctly. It works now, thank you